# How to exclude some nodes in R?

Tags: html, r, rvest

I'm scraping a web site and want to exclude some nodes.

```
url <- "https://www.n11.com/telefon-ve-aksesuarlari/cep-telefonu?q=iphone+11"

gettitles <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes("div.productArea") %>% 
  html_nodes(":not(div.group.listingGroup.set6.promoGroup)") %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="plink"]') %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  tibble()
```

I don't want the titles at the bottom of the page under the pagination. But it doesn't work. It should be 28 but 14 of 42 is prominent. What's wrong with this code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few attributes which differentiate title at the bottom of the page and in the main nodes. We can use one of those attributes and filter the nodes. I have used `"data-ctgid"` here.

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.n11.com/telefon-ve-aksesuarlari/cep-telefonu?q=iphone+11"
nodes <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("div.columnContent") 

nodes[!is.na(nodes %>% html_attr('data-ctgid'))] %>%
   html_nodes('div.pro a') %>%
   html_attr('title')

#[1] "iPHONE 11 128 GB APPLE TÜRKİYE GARANTİLİ"                         
#[2] "APPLE İPHONE 11 64 GB (APPLE TÜRKİYE GARANTİLİ)"                  
#[3] "Apple iPhone 11 128GB (2 Yıl Apple Türkiye Garantili)"            
#[4] "Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max 64 GB (2 Yıl Apple Türkiye Garantili)"    
#[5] "Apple iPhone 11 Pro 64 GB (2 Yıl Apple Türkiye Garantili)"        
#[6] "APPLE İPHONE 11 64 GB (2 YIL APPLE TÜRKİYE GARANTİLİ)"       
#...
#...
#[27] "iPhone 11 Pro 64 GB"                                              
#[28] "Apple iPhone 11 64 GB (Distribütör Garantili)"
```